# Can't override AuthenticationForm

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

I try to add an additional check that the user has certain text in the field, but I can not redefine the AuthenticationForm.
Forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm as BaseAuthenticationForm 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class AuthenticationForm(BaseAuthenticationForm):
        print('here')
```

or

```
class AuthenticationForm(BaseAuthenticationForm):
    def clean(self):
        print('hi')
        return self.cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        model = User
```

does not work. The feeling is that I do not get into them because the output of the line is the first command.
Views.py:

```
from .forms import AuthenticationForm

def LogIn(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        print('hi there')
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        print(form.errors)
else:
    form = AuthenticationForm()
return render(request, 'userprocessing/login.html', {'form': form})
```

all `print` I use only to check what works. What am I doing wrong? The registration form has redefined and with the authorization of the problem.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "The feeling is that I do not get into them because the output of the line is the first command."

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I use print to test the input method of the class. The text from the print is not output.